# Configuring my route in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm trying to configure my route so that it reflects the tab the user is on within the page. Pics below.
If the state is on 'Upcoming' I want to just have a route with the state = Upcoming like this with no month or year

> www.mysite.com/Schedule/Host/Upcoming

if the state is 'Past' I need to require a month and year like this

> www.mysite.com/Schedule/Host/Past/March/2016

The problem is that I can enter in just the controller and action

> Schedule/Host

and the route gets through to the action method. I want to prevent this.

here are some examples

> www.mysite.com/Schedule/Host -> no pass with just the controller and action
>
> www.mysite.com/Schedule/Host/Upcoming -> ok with no month or year
>
> www.mysite.com/Schedule/Host/Past/March/2016 -> when state = past you must provide a month and year

Here is what the page will look like with Upcoming as the state

> https://localhost:44368/Schedule/Host/Upcoming

[image]

Here is what it will look like with past as the state

> https://localhost:44368/Schedule/Host/Past/March/2017

[image]

Here is my routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ScheduleByState",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{state}/{month}/{year}",
            defaults: new { month = UrlParameter.Optional, year = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

Here is my action method Host

```
public ActionResult Host(string state, string month, string year)
{
    ViewBag.MenuItem = "schedule";
    ViewBag.UserMenuItem = "host";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: string is nullable type. You need to handle the parameter value check in the action method level. Also you may consider using the appropriate types (int for month and year)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand your question correctly

but seems you have to set multiple routes to satisfy your requirement

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "home",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/"
            }
        );    

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ScheduleByState",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/Upcoming/"
           }
        );


routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ScheduleByState",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/Past/{month}/{year}"
           }
        );
```

another solution is use regex in your router parameter, it will make things more complicated, so if you have only these fixed states, probably more rules will be easier to handle